# Command not found even thought it is installed on Linux

Tags: linux, command

I recently installed nodejs in a remote centos server following the instruction on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-a-centos-7-server for installing a package from the node site, since the nodejs that was installed using yum was v 0.something.

The installation went well, and node seems to be working, but only when I execute

`/usr/local/bin/node` or npm for that matter.

If I try just
`node` or `npm` I get the following error:

> -bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory

This is a little strange because my `PATH` does have `/usr/local/bin/`, and if I do
`which node`
I get
    `/usr/local/bin`

Here is a copy/paste from the server

```
[root@v468996 local]# echo $PATH;
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
[root@v468996 local]# /usr/local/bin/node -v
v11.5.0
[root@v468996 local]# which node
/usr/local/bin/node
[root@v468996 local]# node
-bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

*Note* I know I can just make symlink on `/usr/bin`, so I'm not really asking about that, I want to know why node won't run even though it is installed, and in a location within `PATH`

Comment: That, to me, suggests that you had a different version of node.js installed previously, and that you removed that in favour of what you have now; but the shell still remembers the old location. Have you tried logging out and back in?

Comment: Nope, haven't tried that, but what you describe is exactly the case. I had an old version installed, and then removed, and re-installed a new one. I will log out, and then back in to see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 0):

As @tink said, this seemed to be the shell remembering the old node location.